# Identifying cryptography algorithm

Tags: static-analysis, decryption, cryptography, c#

I have a decryption algorithm that has been pulled from an x86 binary and converted into C# code. The C# works perfectly to decrypt data, but I'd like to identify the algorithm in use, so I could (among other things) possibly replace the extracted algorithm with an identical one from a third party library (like [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)) but I don't know where to begin.

I'm including my code below for reference. I'd like to find out how to even go about identifying such a thing. (Of course, the name of the algorithm would be greatly appreciated as well!)

```
public class Crypto
{
    private static uint[] _MCInitVector = {
        0xDB792195, 0xE63BF923, 0x4F6F076D, 0x122CDED5, 0xDA711220, 0x4F6FCEE6, 0x45E45C44, 0xCF852932,
        0x469ADBF6, 0x5E12481F, 0x682D2354, 0xBDD21105, 0x5BB5F3E6, 0x6E8C82CA, 0xD0FDD8E3, 0xBE4CB2DF,
        0xE3EB3F01, 0xD03D3F32, 0x77A4E3FF, 0xDF17D4B5, 0x2AC710AC, 0x5ACAC8ED, 0x703BD8E4, 0x1D9C3B3B,
        0x4564A5D2, 0xB0224742, 0xB5A3048A, 0xA35A3F55, 0xCA33744F, 0xF1AEC0A0, 0x0BF4B1A4, 0x04038654,
        0x7C65A9EC, 0xAA41DC51, 0xE5096687, 0x1D433C75, 0x35DE20AF, 0xDB75DA77, 0x230A8E81, 0x18BE6B31,
        0x8D8857BA, 0x0EC016A2, 0x2FF6FB27, 0x37D3EB09, 0x91A6A259, 0x13E0EA7B, 0x07926A43, 0x21DF97F9,
        0x24FD4BEB, 0x10315AA3, 0x58D70DF3, 0x7C56F52D, 0x1ABF4E8F, 0x50E140B0, 0xE1E9FEB2, 0x90380A5E,
        0xEA3761D3, 0x583B843B, 0xF0F9496F, 0xC9FCD225, 0x35EC4846, 0x550CFA8B, 0x574DD012, 0x66C3ABF9,
        0x55A7DBF8, 0x510A4DAE, 0xFF1738CC, 0x9AC85D2F, 0x3A7704F5, 0xDDB85A5C, 0x86A50929, 0xFB01BD4F,
        0x877DDF76, 0x187EF004, 0x912E5B3E, 0xEBE1CBDD, 0x354F0206, 0x9D889D03, 0x910D16EF, 0xA67178A7,
        0xC2DEEEDF, 0xE433A4BC, 0x474B91F7, 0x14A28299, 0xCBAD7D66, 0x494D39DF, 0x8B6BB28E, 0xCDCC33EE,
        0xAF37C9D3, 0x9D79794F, 0x6B2C05ED, 0xA8823F18, 0x6225D7ED, 0x292E7345, 0xA04CE9DF, 0x951ABE7F,
        0x72C3CC98, 0xCD1E0582, 0x41224C23, 0x90D26E39, 0xC75B1461, 0xE0B5DBD1, 0x83BA4F78, 0x2A072F2B,
        0xA1A24F28, 0xB3BF06C8, 0xD5335518, 0x186662AC, 0xBC71C21F, 0x2BFC24A8, 0xDBB15F07, 0x076C83F5,
        0xBD656129, 0x507A23D6, 0xB3CE5930, 0xD68E24EF, 0xE82CAF40, 0xA53C0493, 0x79CE3BB7, 0x030FEF29,
        0x347E8A30, 0xFF6E9D5C, 0xCE9B9A04, 0xBC4E5140, 0x949BBE83, 0xCB8B3DBE, 0xAE1D5F44, 0x21148102,
        0x754E9EAF, 0xF2DEAE15, 0xF2EB3A8C, 0x8B1614AE, 0x6ED005B6, 0xCA16DD83, 0x29BD701B, 0xAA6201C9,
        0x58CE4025, 0x9C6121CB, 0x11C03985, 0xEFFC2A2A, 0x4136605B, 0x7F30DDFD, 0x19ECCC35, 0x4D6E1426,
        0x6360EE03, 0xE69CB55A, 0xD181A69D, 0x7E69A4C7, 0x91B4C97C, 0x9BA0F967, 0xE05438A6, 0xF6A6AB45,
        0xD0808096, 0xCE1DB289, 0x8FDF796F, 0x4D3B9B25, 0xA4AD9AE6, 0x5DF9105F, 0x71B1FD3E, 0xF90A6F7C,
        0xEE1D1310, 0x183B6922, 0x2AD9A280, 0x50EAD939, 0x0B5990F6, 0xEAB6D31C, 0xD1F23104, 0x3FA68196,
        0xA228DCCC, 0x68C10912, 0x9003CF9C, 0xB92E58C4, 0x9FBBA10F, 0x3DA05555, 0xAE52996D, 0x8F0A3B2C,
        0x12F8D4DF, 0x02DF25C9, 0x51D99D11, 0x950AEAD2, 0xFFF87B29, 0xCDA6B1E7, 0x13056DC7, 0x189BA81A,
        0xA23C22E1, 0x0F9E5E7F, 0x799B23CD, 0x53DB90F6, 0xA388548B, 0xB9C0D3E5, 0x753BB810, 0xC3768EFD,
        0x2D66B7F2, 0x16EEC5CB, 0x4490D722, 0xF813E0E6, 0xD02DC104, 0x1FE5CA4F, 0x18A27E69, 0x191699FF,
        0xB366A330, 0x4B01495D, 0x5529AD4D, 0x48F2FE87, 0x926C55F1, 0x53491F9B, 0x875BA8D1, 0xEF2C3CD8,
        0xE50C89F9, 0x5201768C, 0x1A5C4B35, 0x114C0C76, 0x77D8B1DF, 0x75E77E8A, 0x39826BA2, 0x3FFACC4F,
        0xF5FF4FF7, 0xA0B10525, 0xFD46ED4F, 0xE97C9F45, 0x568CB141, 0xD45C1365, 0x788B2B7E, 0xABAA5158,
        0x73AD6AEA, 0x041E5FCA, 0x0BE48855, 0x01C285AF, 0x0B2EFB29, 0x49655AEE, 0xABBF0B3C, 0x958E4617,
        0x0A8CD37A, 0x871758F9, 0x0DB1A84D, 0xE453974A, 0x78308BD6, 0x7456A7EB, 0x76FF0F79, 0x3C1957D9,
        0xD6E89EE6, 0x4DB3A5B2, 0xBAC849BA, 0xC68E2110, 0xE8F9F2EB, 0x970F676E, 0x034377B6, 0xF0DC724F,
        0xFF290056, 0xD3B7F2FF, 0x72DF023B, 0x3021ACA2, 0x352EE316, 0xE046B5CA, 0xE94E08BC, 0x41BFFB5A
    };

    private byte[] _decryptKey;
    private uint[] _decryptSet;
    private uint _decryptState1;
    private uint _decryptState2;
    private uint _decryptState3;
    private int _decryptSetIndex;
    private int _decryptKeyIndex;

    public uint Seed { get; set; }

    public Crypto(uint seed)
    {
        this.Seed = seed;

        _decryptKey = new byte[128];
        _decryptSet = new uint[512];

        // round 0
        Array.Copy(_MCInitVector, _decryptSet, 256);
        Array.Clear(_decryptSet, 256, 256);
        _decryptState1 = seed;
        _decryptState2 = 0;
        _decryptState3 = 0;
        _decryptSetIndex = 0;
        uint key = getNextKey();

        // round 1
        Array.Copy(_MCInitVector, _decryptSet, 256);
        Array.Clear(_decryptSet, 256, 256);
        _decryptState1 = seed;
        _decryptState2 = key;
        _decryptState3 = 0;
        _decryptSetIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            key = getNextKey();
        }

        // round 2
        Array.Copy(_MCInitVector, _decryptSet, 256);
        Array.Clear(_decryptSet, 256, 256);
        _decryptState1 = key;
        _decryptState2 = 0;
        _decryptState3 = 0;
        _decryptSetIndex = 0;

        // fill decrypt keys
        _decryptKeyIndex = 31;
        for (int i = 124; i >= 0; i -= 4)
        {
            BitConverter.GetBytes(getNextKey()).CopyTo(_decryptKey, i);
        }
    }

    private uint getNextKey()
    {
        int i = (--_decryptSetIndex);
        if (i < 256)
        {
            uint var1 = _decryptState1;
            uint var2 = _decryptState2 + (++_decryptState3);

            i = 0;
            while (i < 256)
            {
                uint j, k;
                var1 = (var1 ^ (var1 << 13)) + _decryptSet[(i + 128) & 0xff];
                j = _decryptSet[i];
                k = _decryptSet[i] = _decryptSet[(j & 0x3ff) >> 2] + var1 + var2;
                var2 = _decryptSet[i + 256] = _decryptSet[((k >> 8) & 0x3ff) >> 2] + j;
                i++;
                var1 = (var1 ^ (var1 >> 6)) + _decryptSet[(i + 128) & 0xff];
                j = _decryptSet[i];
                k = _decryptSet[i] = _decryptSet[(j & 0x3ff) >> 2] + var1 + var2;
                var2 = _decryptSet[i + 256] = _decryptSet[((k >> 8) & 0x3ff) >> 2] + j;
                i++;
                var1 = (var1 ^ (var1 << 2)) + _decryptSet[(i + 128) & 0xff];
                j = _decryptSet[i];
                k = _decryptSet[i] = _decryptSet[(j & 0x3ff) >> 2] + var1 + var2;
                var2 = _decryptSet[i + 256] = _decryptSet[((k >> 8) & 0x3ff) >> 2] + j;
                i++;
                var1 = (var1 ^ (var1 >> 16)) + _decryptSet[(i + 128) & 0xff];
                j = _decryptSet[i];
                k = _decryptSet[i] = _decryptSet[(j & 0x3ff) >> 2] + var1 + var2;
                var2 = _decryptSet[i + 256] = _decryptSet[((k >> 8) & 0x3ff) >> 2] + j;
                i++;
            }

            _decryptState1 = var1;
            _decryptState2 = var2;
            i = _decryptSetIndex = 511;
        }

        return _decryptSet[i];
    }


    public void DecodePacket(ref byte[] packet)
    {
        int len = packet.Length;

        // Poster's note: Packet is post-fixed with a 4 byte checksum, hence this subtraction
        len -= 4;
        int idx = _decryptKeyIndex * 4;
        int i = 6; // Poster's Note: Actual packet data starts at index 6, index 5 and below are flags/metadata
        // block decryption (OFB mode)
        while (i < len)
        {
            int j = idx & 0x1f; idx += 4;
            packet[i++] ^= _decryptKey[j++];
            packet[i++] ^= _decryptKey[j++];
            packet[i++] ^= _decryptKey[j++];
            packet[i++] ^= _decryptKey[j++];
        }
        len += 4;
        // process left bytes
        while (i < len)
        {
            packet[i++] ^= _decryptKey[(idx++) & 0x7f];
        }

        // update key stream
        idx = _decryptKeyIndex;
        BitConverter.GetBytes(getNextKey()).CopyTo(_decryptKey, idx);
        _decryptKeyIndex = (idx + 31) & 0x1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always feed the original binary to IDA and use the plugin [Findcrypt2](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=28) to identify the algorithms used. Other than this the [Kanal](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Kanal.shtml) plugin for PeiD can also detect cryptography used.
Another tool for the same task is [Hash & Crypto Detector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/Hash-Crypto-Detector.shtml)

Comment: IDA found AES (and I confirmed it was being used here). How that gave rise to my C# class is a question probably better left  unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, it resembles HC-256, but it's hard to say for certain without running it and comparing the input/output to an existing HC-256 implementation.